# white gaps in between columns in rshiny

Tags: r

I'm building UI for a RShiny App. I want to set up the background color to be all black. However, there are empty white gaps in between columns even if the total column width is 12.

Here is the screenshot of the output:

[image]

Code sample:

```
# static top
  fluidRow(
    column(12, 
           div(sliderInput("slider_fia_prod", "Issue Year:", fia_start_yr, fia_end_yr, value=c(fia_start_yr,fia_end_yr), width = '100%'), 
               style = "height: 130px; background-color: black; color: white")),
    column(10, 
           div(plotlyOutput("fia_general_hor_bar"), align = "center",
               style = "height: 90px; background-color: black")),
    column(1,
          div(checkboxGroupInput('by_mva_type', label = 'By MVA Type', choices = list('MVA' = 'A', 'Non-MVA' = 'B'), selected = c('A','B')), 
              style = "font-size: 12px; padding: 0px; height: 90px; background-color: black; color: white", align = "left")),
    column(1,
          div(checkboxGroupInput('by_gmwb_rider', label = 'By GMWB Rider', choices = list('GMWB' = 'G', 'Non-GMWB' = 'N'), selected = c('N','G')), 
              style = "font-size: 12px; padding: 0px; height: 90px; background-color: black; color: white", align = "left")))
```

Comment: It seems like this is the _gutter width_ you're seeing (spacing between columns). Could you try applying the background color onto the fluidRow instead? That way you don't have to specify it on every column too.

Comment: Thanks! I used the code tags$area(style="background-color: black;") but it failed. I guess it's because I'm not using the right tag.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap places "gutter" width spacing between columns. Check out [this page](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/layout-guide.html#supported-devices) from the Shiny docs, they provided a table to break down the gutter sizing for you.

You can apply the `background-color: black` onto your fluidRow instead, and then you also no longer need to apply it to each column.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I used tags$area(style = "background-color: black;") but it failed.